# MPI zero count data exchange

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

I have some questions regarding exchanging zero-count data (say, by MPI_Send and MPI_Recv), for which I have trouble finding answers in MPI docs:

1) As I understand, it is legal (by MPI standard) to have count equal 0. Or is it implementation defined?

1a) In functions like `MPI_Gatherv` can some counts be zero?

**2) If count is zero, does buffer still have to be a valid pointer? Or can it be `NULL`/uninitialized?**

3) Even if count is 0, there is some communication over the network, i.e. some header/meta data is still communicated. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) It is legal to have count equal to zero.

1a) It is legal to have some counts to be zero in `MPI_Gatherv()` (and `MPI_Scatterv(),`MPI_Alltoallv()` and friends)

2) The standard does not mandate the pointer to be valid if the count is zero

3) A zero message size is a message, and as a direct consequence, some metadata is exchanged. `MPI_Recv(..., count=0, ...)` only returns after a zero size message has been received (and hence sent), and that could not happen if no data was sent.